# Browsers do not accept a valid encryption certificate

Tags: encryption, ssl, certificate

I used to import self signed certificates generated by me to the Windows' Root CA storage. It always did the trick.

Now I encountered a self signed certificate generated by our company as a part of a product. It is installed along with the product.

When I go to a web site of the application, all browsers (MS Edge, Vivaldi, Chrome) show that the certificate is invalid, but when I view certificate's properties with the same browser, everything is valid.

How could it be and what is the problem? Importing this certificate to Root CA storage does not help.

Comment: Browser vendors have recently tightened their validity rules. I wouldn't be surprised if some of the UI hasn't kept up with the recent changes. For example, certificates may not have a validity period longer than something like 821 days (2 years with a ~90 day grace period). How far apart are your cert's "not valid before" and "not valid after" dates?

Comment: "view certificate's properties with the same browser" - What browser exactly?

Comment: @Spiff: May be a long validity period is a problem. The certificate is valid till year 2044.

Comment: @Paul Okay, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser vendors have recently tightened their validity rules. I wouldn't be surprised if some of the UI hasn't kept up with the recent changes. For example, certificates are no longer allowed to have a validity period longer than something like 821 days (2 years with a ~90 day grace period). If your cert's "not valid before" and "not valid after" dates are farther apart than that, you should regenerate your cert with a validity period within the new limit.